# Laravel- html tags not load ckeditor text

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, ckeditor

Please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LknNx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdnuw.png)

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), since this is not a question. But merely a collection of images where we have to make sense of ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
{!! $item->product_description !!}
```

The string will auto escape when using `{{ $item->product_description }}`.